# ¿Como inicializar select2 dinámicamente con jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

**Dentro de mi formulario poseo una tabla que me permite agregar campos dinamicos de entrada a traves de jquery**, unos de estos campos es un input del tipo select, para este select utilizo el plugin select2. 
**El inconveniente es el siguiente cada ves que inicializo mi formulario ya sea para crear o editar el select2 solo se inicializa en la primer fila de mi tabla dinamica** como se puede  ver en la imagen

Primer fila de mi tabla:

[image: primer fila]

en la segunda imagen se puede observar que en la segunda fila de mi tabla el campo posicion tiene la apariencia de un "select normal"

[image: segunda fila]

Entoces lo que pretendo es que por cada fila que agregue a mi tabla se inicialice el select2 en mi campo posicion

este es mi tabla dinamica:

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" id="dynamicTable">              
                    <thead>    
                        <tr>
                            <th width="5%">Posición</th>
                            <th width="20%">Herramienta</th>                 
                            <th width="20%">Inserto</th>                 
                            <th width="20%">Calidad</th>                       
                            <th width="5%"><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i></button></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @forelse ($piece->tools as $p)  
                        <tr> 
                            <input name="addmore[{{$loop->index}}][insert_id]" value="{{ $p->insert->id }}" hidden/>
                            <input name="addmore[{{$loop->index}}][tool_id]" value="{{ $p->id }}" hidden/>
                            <td>
                                <select name="addmore[{{$loop->index}}][position]" id="position" class="form-control select2" placeholder="Posición">
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    @foreach ($tools as $tool)          
                                        <option value="{{ $tool->id }}"
                                        {{ old('position', $p->id) == $tool->id ? 'selected' : ''}}>
                                        {{ $tool->position }}</option>                     
                                    @endforeach  
                                </select>
                            </td>                       
                            <td><input type="text" name="addmore[{{$loop->index}}][code_tool]" value="{{ $p->code_tool }}" placeholder="Herramienta"class="form-control"/></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="addmore[{{$loop->index}}][code_insert]" value="{{ $p->insert->code_insert }}" placeholder="Inserto" class="form-control"/></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="addmore[{{$loop->index}}][quality]" value="{{ $p->insert->quality }}" placeholder="Calidad" class="form-control"/></td>
                        </tr> 
                        @empty
                            <td colspan="4"></td>
                            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr"><i class="fa fa-trash "></i></button></td>
                        @endforelse 
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Este es mi script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var cantidadDeFilasEnLaTabla = $('#dynamicTable >tbody >tr').length;
    var i = cantidadDeFilasEnLaTabla ? cantidadDeFilasEnLaTabla: 0;  

    $("#add").click(function(){

        ++i;       

        $("#dynamicTable").append( 
        '<tr>' + 
            '<td>' + 
                '<select name="addmore['+i+'][position]" id="position" class="form-control select2" placeholder="Posición">' +
                    '<option value=""></option>' +
                    '@foreach($tools as $tool)' +                        
                        '<option value="{{ $tool->position }}">{{ $tool->position }}</option>' + 
                    '@endforeach' + 
                '</select>' + 
            '</td>'+


            '<td><input type="text" name="addmore['+i+'][code_tool]" placeholder="Herramienta" class="form-control" /></td>' + 
            '<td><input type="text" name="addmore['+i+'][code_insert]" placeholder="Inserto" class="form-control" /></td>' + 
            '<td><input type="text" name="addmore['+i+'][quality]" placeholder="Calidad" class="form-control"/></td>' + 
            '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr"><i class="fa fa-trash "></i></button></td>' +
            '</tr>'            

        );   

        $('#position').select2({
            placeholder: 'P',
            tags: true,
            tokenSeparators: [',']
        });       


    });     


    $(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function(){  
         $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    }); 


</script>
```

**ACTUALIZADO 1**

Este es problmea que me surgio ahora  cada select tiene un ancho distinto:

[image: select2]

Asi se ve mi script en este momento:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var cantidadDeFilasEnLaTabla = $('#dynamicTable >tbody >tr').length;
    var i = cantidadDeFilasEnLaTabla ? cantidadDeFilasEnLaTabla: 0;  

    $("#add").click(function(){

        ++i;       

        $("#dynamicTable").append( 
        '<tr>' + 
            '<td>' + 
                '<select name="addmore['+i+'][position]" id="position_' + i +'"  class="form-control select2" placeholder="Posición">' +
                    '<option value=""></option>' +
                    '@foreach($tools as $tool)' +                        
                        '<option value="{{ $tool->position }}">{{ $tool->position }}</option>' + 
                    '@endforeach' + 
                '</select>' + 
            '</td>'+


            '<td><input type="text" name="addmore['+i+'][code_tool]" placeholder="Herramienta" class="form-control" /></td>' + 
            '<td><input type="text" name="addmore['+i+'][code_insert]" placeholder="Inserto" class="form-control" /></td>' + 
            '<td><input type="text" name="addmore['+i+'][quality]" placeholder="Calidad" class="form-control"/></td>' + 
            '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr"><i class="fa fa-trash "></i></button></td>' +
            '</tr>'            

        );   

        $('#position_' + i).select2();  

    });     



    $(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function(){  
         $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    }); 


</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El que generes un mismo id te traerá problemas.
Como te comenta @Arriel es una buena forma generando el select2 para una clase, pero afectará a los que ya estan creados, deberás hacer `destroy` primero a todos.

Te propongo generes un id dinámico por cada elemento creado y posteriormente lo ejecutes con select2

```
<script>
...
'select name="addmore['+i+'][position]" id="position_' + i +'" class="form-control select2" placeholder="Posición">'
...
$('#position_' + i).select2();
</script>

<style>
.select2 {
    width: 100% !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: hola @Jonathan Orta, estoy siguiendo tu comentario por favor revisa mi actualizacion observa como va cambiando el ancho en cada nueva fila que voy agregando

Comment: gracias! estaba convencido que lo podia solucionar  con esto: ```width: 'resolve'```, propiedad del select2, de todos modos funciono con <style>!

Answer (score 2):

Creo el problema es que el id del dropdown es "posicion"

> name="addmore['+i+'][position]" **id="position"**

para todos los dropdowns. Cuando el html se genera, es probable que tengas algo diferente para todos excepto el primero.

Edit: Prueba ver el html generado y ver qué id tienen los elementos dinámicos.

Tal vez quieras utilizar una clase personalizada para cada uno de esos dropdown y utilizar el selector de jquery sobre esa clase, ya que puede ser utilizada por múltiples elementos.

```
$('.claseUnica').select2();
```

Prueba el método, y nos cuentas cómo te fue.

Comment: gracias me fue muy util tu respuesta el problema ahora es con el ancho de cada input el segundo select tiene un ancho distinto que el primero, pero debe ser una propiedad sel select2